# Encerrando um loop, com enter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou querendo encerrar um `while True:` apertando uma tecla, no caso simplesmente apertando enter sem escrever nada.

```
while True:
    key = input("Press enter")
    if key == " ":
        break
    else:
    #loop
```

Como posso faze-lo?

Comment: Precisa deixar o if direto, assim ele vai ficar parado esperando você apertar o botão pra continuar.

Comment: Você pode me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Isso é coisa de faculdade?

Comment: Usa asyncio ou usa pipes.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio-subprocess aqui tem um exemplo. Se for usar pipes é só usar `mkfifo` no terminal do linux pra criar um arquivo do tipo pipe, aí o esquema é FIFO (first in, first out), primeiro a entrar, primeiro a sair. Aí você deixa o seu programa rodando lendo o arquivo com o loop e faz um outro pra escrever nele.

Comment: Você precisa deixar o loop executando enquanto não for pressionado o enter?

Comment: Quero dar o usuario a opção de encerrar o programa apertando enter, se não apertar ele se reinicia, algo do tipo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas corrigindo o seu código ele vai funcionar tbm:

```py
while True:
    a = str(input(""))

    if a == "":
        break
```

Comment: ` a = str(input(""))
  File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: @Gabriel aqui rodou perfeitamente. Tente identar a linha em branco.

Comment: Só lembrando que `input` já retorna uma string, usar o retorno com `str` é redundante e gasta recursos a toa.

Answer (score 1):

Pra solução do problema do modo como esta só precisa remover o espaço entre as aspas.
No seu código seu `if` esta comparando o input com uma string de um caractere que é o espaço `" "`. Quando você aperta o enter em um input sem nenhum caractere você esta mandando uma string vazia `""`, então para solução deve comparar o input com uma string vazia `""`.

O código deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
if a == "":
    break
```